# Elastic Beanstalk PHP Version

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have been deploying a Laravel application to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

When I created the environment (this is the third one I have done) I requested an environment with PHP7.1.

Upon deployment I get all kinds of errors on the server and when I ssh into the environment and do a `php --version` I see this:

> PHP 7.0.25 (cli) (built: Dec  5 2017 18:55:31) ( NTS ) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017
>   Zend Technologies

If I am requesting an environment with 7.1, why does this happen? How can I ensure that I get the right PHP version?

Comment: Same here, I chose PHP 7.1 env but errors come as PHP 7.0.

Comment: Are you uploading any kind of configurations with .ebextensions folder?

Comment: Hey, did you solve this at all?